# Get the username on a self relationship - Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

I'm building a "Follow System" (like twitter) I'm trying to get the Follow username. But i can get only follower_id or followed_id. This is What i got:

//UsersFollowersTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('users_followers');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Followeds', [ //who i'm following
        'className' => 'Users',
        'unique' => true,
        'foreignKey' => 'follower_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'Users.id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Followers', [ //my followers
        'className' => 'Users',
        'unique' => true,
        'foreignKey' => 'followed_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'Users.id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

//UsersTable.php

public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

```
    $this->hasMany('Followed', [
        'className' => 'UsersFollowers',
        //'joinTable' => 'users_followers',
        'unique' => true,
        'foreignKey' => 'follower_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'id'
    ]);

      $this->hasMany('Follower', [
        'className' => 'UsersFollowers',
        //'joinTable' => 'users_followers',
        'unique' => true,
        'foreignKey' => 'followed_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'id'
    ]);


}
```

How can i get the $user->followed "Username"?
//UsersController
 public function view($id = null)
    {

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Collections', 'Images', 'Items', 'Likes', 'Messages', 'Profiles', 'Ratings', 'Followed', 'Follower' ]
    ]);
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Have you used `debug($user->excute());` to see the results?

Answer (score 0):

User has many followed, so `$user->followed` is a `Collection`, loop it:

```
if ($user->has('followed')) {
    foreach ($user->followed as $followed) {
        debug($followed->username);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant get username. Look: